# Center 'the_post_thumbnail' on single post page Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is driving me bonkers, as I recall it worked the other day.

I can't center the image on single post page. Tried different classes, even implemented bootstrap, which should not be needed for such a simple page. It worked perfectly on posts page archive and latest posts on home page.

What am I missing? It's styled in SASS, shouldn't be a conflict with CSS.

Thanks in advance!

```css
#singlepost{
  .blog-image {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h1 {
        color: #fff;
        @include PTSansNarrowRegular;
        font-size: 50px;
        color:  black;
        line-height: 45px;
        letter-spacing: -1.5px;
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto 27px auto;
        /*text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;*/
    }
    p {
        padding-left: 60px;
        padding-right: 60px;
        text-align: justify;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<? get_header(); ?>
<section id="singlepost">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><h1><? the_title(); ?></h1></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 image-responsive blog-image"> 
                <? the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                <p><? the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>    
<? get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdYmqr

Comment: Thank you Michael! Yes, the 'text-center' tag did it.  One of those days I'm losing it, lol. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem. I'll submit as an answer since you have other responses now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center an image, you can use `text-align: center` on the parent, but if you're using bootstrap, you should use their helper class `.text-center`

```css
.blog-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  @include PTSansNarrowRegular;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto 27px auto;
  /*text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;*/
}

p {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="singlepost">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><h1><? the_title(); ?></h1></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center image-responsive blog-image"> 
                <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                <p><? the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `text-align: center;` to the image's parent container

```
.blog-image {
  text-align: center;
}
```